# Highcharts - Using 'errorbar' type overrides axis interval

Tags: highcharts

I am trying to set my X and Y axes to have set minimums, maximums and intervals. Easy enough according to the docs - and indeed I have had no problem working with Highcharts to date - in fact the complete opposite, it's an awesome, awesome tool. However, when I add errors bars to my line series', it seems to knock out the x-axis - http://jsfiddle.net/Su44W/

Simply changing to series' type to `arearange` (http://jsfiddle.net/46dsn/1), providing the same data points [x, low, high], the chart now respects my `min`, `max` and `tickInterval` on the x-axis. So this begs the question, is this a bug or and I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From my understanding the `errorbar` causes the axis to consider itself part of a "column-like chart". That is, the points on the axis have a span. The result of this is that this piece of code is ran to prevent more ticks than there are points (found on [line 7194 of the source](http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.src.js)):

```
// In column-like charts, don't cramp in more ticks than there are points (#1943)
if (axis.pointRange) {
    axis.tickInterval = mathMax(axis.pointRange, axis.tickInterval);
}
```

I'm not exactly sure how this solves the problem, but in some way setting the `pointRange` of the `errorbar` series causes the axis to use that `pointRange` for the axis as well. I'm guessing it just uses the maximum point range of all series, or something similar. This means your specified `tickInterval` will be the "max" in the above `mathMax`-function. Like this:

```
{
    name: 'Series 1 error bars',
    data: [
        [4,7.26,7.34],
        [12,6.85,7.06],
        [26,6.92,7.12]
    ],                      
    linkedTo: ':previous',
    color: "#013879",
    zIndex: 0,
    whiskerLength: 7,
    type: 'errorbar',
    pointRange: 0
}
```

Check [this JSFiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/Su44W/1/) for `pointRange` in action.

The negative effect that this will have is that the top and bottom line for your errorbars will have very short width. You can counter this by specifying a `pointWidth` for the series as well, as in [this JSFiddle demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/Su44W/2/).

Comment: Very good answer - I had noticed in testing the `errorbar` behaved like a column but wasn't aware of `pointRange` option which is an elegant solution. As an aside, while `pointWidth` did elongate my whisker length, the option `whiskerLength` works as expected without it, so not necessary in my opinion. Thank you.